# .XLS to php/html table

Tags: php, jquery, html, excel

I'm working as IT Administrator at University.
I'm sorry for my English, not the best there is :)

The workers makes student's timesheets/tables in xls files and I upload them to our website for download.

I made a webpage to display xls files using http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/, but its pain in the ass to maintain and it looks awful (far away from what it looks in excel)

Example of how I had to make it work:

NOTE: Dump function that the php-excel-reader has does not work correctly!

```
$n1 = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("tvk/n1.xls");

echo '<font size=4><table cellspacing="0" style="width:900px; height:625px; border:1px solid gray">';
$index = 9;             
while($index <= 50){
echo '<tr><td>';
echo $n1->val($index, 'A');
echo '</td><td>';
echo $n1->val($index, 'B');
echo '</td><td>';
echo $n1->val($index, 'C');
echo '</td></tr>';
$index++;
}
echo '</table></font>';
```

Problem is that every time they change the sheets and they get longer or shorter I have to edit the index... Or maybe there is a way to simplify this code to count automatically when to stop creating lines?

I am looking for a tool, JS or php to read and display xls files, no conversion.
I want it to display latest files that I have uploaded to the website.

I am desperate for something simple to do everything automatically on server side.

Comment: Why not look at other libraries like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) that can output directly to HTML, and are still maintained?

Comment: I tryed, have no idea how that thing works and use it... its just full of useful stuff but no explanation how to use it. I tried it few times but got nothing out of it. Also I need a quick and light code for fast usage

Comment: So the mass of documentation and examples are useless? Four lines of code : `require_once dirname './PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php'; $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("tvk/n1.xls"); $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML'); $objWriter->save('php://output');`

Comment: @Mark Baker Thanks that did work, but the output is destroyed lines jumping on other lines text cut off, any fix for that ?

Comment: Without knowing what you mean by `destroyed lines jumping on other lines text cut off` I can't tell you if there's any fix or not